# Why does getOwnPropertyDescriptor return undefined on event.target?

Tags: javascript, html

I've come across this method and out of curiosity I'm trying it out on an HTML page with a simple text input field.

The JS code is:

```
document.addEventListener( "input", function( e ) {
    console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( e.target, 'value' ) )
});
```

Why doesn't the method return the configuration for the `value` property?

Comment: It's probably not an own property.

Comment: this is because you object does not have own property. if you do `e.target.xxx = "xxx"` then running `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e.target,'xxx')` will give you output because now your object does have xxx property. HTML attributes and properties are not considered here.